# Typescript ternary expression error saying the condition will always return 'false'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm getting the following Typescript error:

> This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'TItem' and
>   '"Chat"' have no overlap.  TS2367

for the code below:

```
const { menu } = state
return (
          <Transition items={menu}>
                {menu => menu === "Chat" // this is where the error occurs
                       ? (props => 
                            <>
                                <section style={props}>
                                    First Section
                                </section>
                            </>
                        )
                        :   
                        (props => 
                            <>
                                <section style={props}>
                                    Second Section
                                </section>
                            </>
                        ) 
                }
            </Transition>
)
```

The state `menu` is from my reducer:

```
interface MyContextType {
    menu?: any,
}

const Context = createContext<MyContextType>({
    menu: null
})
```

where the `action.payload` is a string type like "Chat".  So `console.log(menu)` will show "Chat".  Eliminating the `=== "Chat"` portion from `menu === "Chat"` allows the code to work perfectly fine, but only when I add the condition, I get the error.

Comment: You can avoid the error by casting menu to a string (`<string>menu === "Chat"`). I can't say how `TItem` is defined, except that it's probably not a string type. This type of cast bypasses normal type checking mechanisms so it should only be used as a last resort.

Comment: You could also try casting `state` to your `MyContextType` interface, e.g., `const { menu } = <MyContextType>state`. This might be preferable if there's no other way to get the types recognized based on your original `Context` definition.

Answer (score 0):

`Menu` is a type `TItem` which is not a string. So a `TItem` has no overlap with string. I'm guessing there is a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) which isn't being passed.

I found the library `react-spring` uses `TItem`. Are you using that?

If you give more info on where `menu` get's its type, I'll add a more specific answer.

By the way, it's challenging to read when you don't put in typings in Typescript and leave everything inferred except for `null` and `any`. For example, instead of `menu =>` put `(menu: SomeType) =>`. This will help a lot with avoiding these types of errors. As a rule of thumb I try to never use `any` or `null`. Instead I use union types (Often these can be avoided too) and `unknown` if I want to have a variable that can contain no value which allows the use of optionals.